# What triggers a Control re-rendering after the initial page load?

Tags: sapui5

I was working with Controls in SAPUI5 and saw events like **onBeforeRendering** and **onAfterRendering** on them; I supposed a Control was rendered only one time (in the initial loading of the page); However, are there other occasions that re-render a control without full a page reload? And in what occasions makes sense to re-render a control? How it is useful to the developer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A control is usually re-rendered when

- a property changes
- an aggregation is manipulated
- an aggregated control requests so

To be precise, any of the above only invalidates the control which tells the UI5 runtime core that re-rendering is necessary (which then happens asynchronously for performance reasons).

Depending on the implementation, re-rendering can be suppressed. E.g. the `sap.m.Text` control doesn't invalidate the control when the `text` property changes but just manipulates its DOM directly.

For the the majority of scenarios, you don't need to worry about re-rendering. It's being taken care of by the UI5 runtime. In fact, for most scenarios, when you need to explicitly re-render/invalidate a control, there's probably something wrong with your implementation.